# Set elevation to View automatically the elevation of the Toolbar, how to change this?

Tags: android, xml, android-appcompat, android-actionbaractivity, android-elevation

I'm using a theme that will not show the ActionBar by default:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

However, I'm replacing it with Toolbar in xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    ... >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_VenueDetail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/MainColor" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="@color/MainColor"
        android:elevation="@dimen/default_elevation"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

in OnCreate:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_VenueDetail);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

The expected result is a flat Toolbar and a shadow below the LinearLayout, which is exactly what preview in Android Studio shows me:

[image: preview on Nexus 4]

However in real life, the Toolbar has also taken effect:

[image: screenshot of my Nexus 5]

I want to just put the shadow below another View and keep my Toolbar flat, how to achieve this? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Do not set the toolbar as a support actionbar. You can still set navigation button, title and inflate menu on the toolbar but the elevation shouldn't be applied unless you set it explicitly in code or in the activity layout.

Having said that, make sure that the removing the elevation is not against the principles of [material design](http://www.google.com/design/spec/what-is-material/objects-in-3d-space.html#objects-in-3d-space-elevation-android-).